# Form values should retain after page postback

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I am handling application level error in global.asax. I am displaying error information to user in bootstrap popup modal. After that I am redirecting user to the same page where error occurred. But as page is refreshing,whatever data is entered by user it is getting lost. Could you please help me how to prevent data loss? As there are many pages in my application, is there any consolidated approch so that I can apply it at application level?

Comment: if it's a popup, is it necessary to redirect them to where the error occurred?

Comment: Can you not store the form values in the .Net Session, ad then retrieve when the view is loaded?

Comment: @Icepickle 
Yes. Actually if the user close modal then he should be see the page where error occurred.

Comment: @G.Hunt
I tried to do use viewstate and Request.form, but I thought it wont be feasible.

Comment: Actually the requirement is to show error details to user in Bootstrap modal popup as soon as error occurred anywhere in application. I have defined the Bootstrap modal in master page and opening it once error occurred. But  as we cant call javascript functions from the gloabal.asax page I have to redirect user to same page again to show that modal. But whatever data has entered by user is lost. Do you have any other solution instead of redirecting? Is there anyway to open bootstrap modal from global.asax?

Comment: I found this link https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7655/Persisting-the-state-of-a-web-page but i didnt understand how to use it